# how to select row in spinner for known rowid?

Tags: android, spinner

When i open Activity for EditRecord i want to select spinner row for adequate value in edited record
I find code like below, but its ok for few records in spinner, but when spinner.cursor contains many records i think its not right idea.
Is any other method to select spinner row for known rowid ?

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(...));
for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
   Cursor value = (Cursor) spinner.getItemAtPosition(i);
   long id = value.getLong(value.getColumnIndex("_id");
   if (id == rowid) {
      spinner.setSelection(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: I didnt get what you are tring to do from above code you are enumerating all spinner values and then setting them as selection I dont think this is what you wanted

Comment: I want to select row in spinner control for given recordId. In codae avoe i go for each record for locate what position has given rowid. Next i select this record. This code do what i want, but its not efficient, i looking for better solution: see subject

Answer (score 0):

Why are you getting a cursor and looking p the column index every time?  Simply do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
   long id = spinner.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
   if (id == rowid) {
      spinner.setSelection(i);
   }
}
```